# SQL Join across multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm creating a DB in SQLite to record race results and SQL queries to then display the data.

I have 1 table for racers and one for the results.

**Racers**

| racerID | racerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark |
| 2 | Simon |
| 3 | Geoff |

**Results**

| resultID | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

How can I display names in all the positions instead of just their IDs?

| resultID | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark | Simon | Geoff |
| 2 | Simon | Geoff | Mark |
| 3 | Mark | Geoff | Simon |

I have managed to get it to work for column 1st.

```
select Racers.racerName as "1st", Results."2nd",Results."3rd"
from Results
inner join Racers on Results."1st"=Racers.racerID;
```

But when I try to get the other columns a similar way I get an error.

```
select Racers.racerName as "1st", Racers.racerName as "2nd",Racers.racerName as "3rd"
from Results
inner join Racers on Results."1st"=Racers.racerID
inner join Racers on Results."2nd"=Racers.racerID
inner join Racers on Results."3rd"=Racers.racerID;
```

I'm sure I am overlooking something very basic, but can not figure out how to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need separate aliases for each table reference:

```
select r1.racerName as "1st", r2.racerName as "2nd", r3.racerName as "3rd"
from Results r join
     Racers r1
     on r."1st" = r1.racerID join
     Racers r2 
     on r."2nd" = r2.racerID join
     Racers r3
     on r."3rd" = r3.racerID;
```